# Having a list and trying to make a polynomial in Python (symbolic calculation)

Tags: python, list, sympy

Suppose I have the following list:

```
f=[1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2]
```

I can count how many of each integers exists in the list using two methods.

First:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(f)
#Counter({1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2})
```

or second:

```
[[x,f.count(x)] for x in set(f)]
#[[1, 3], [2, 1], [3, 4], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 2]]
```

the second method is preferable as it throws me with a list. 
Now I want to turn the output into polynomial where the first element of sublists would be power of x and the second element of sublists would be the coefficients and finally sum them to form a polynomial, such that I get:

```
3 x + x^2 + 4 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^6
```

To make this polynomial I used Sympy as follow:

```
from sympy import Array, tensorproduct
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import transpose
A = Array([x])
B = Array([x[1] for x in [[x,f.count(x)] for x in set(f)]])
tensorproduct(A, B)
#[[3*x, x, 4*x, 3*x, 2*x, 2*x]]
```

now I am not sure how to raise for the correct power of x ? Also is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
from sympy import poly, var
from collections import Counter

x = var("x")
f = [1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2]
count = Counter(f)
p = sum(coeff * x ** exp for exp, coeff in count.items())
# 2*x**6 + 2*x**5 + 3*x**4 + 4*x**3 + x**2 + 3*x
```

where [`**` is used for exponentiation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operators#operator.pow).

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to actually evaluate the polynomial, or just get a pretty string?

```
from collections import Counter
superscript_digits = "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"

f=[1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2]
coeffs_by_exp = Counter(f)
print(' + '.join("{}x{}".format(coeff, superscript_digits[exp])
                     for exp, coeff in coeffs_by_exp.items()))
```

Gives:

```
3x¹ + 1x² + 4x³ + 3x⁴ + 2x⁵ + 2x⁶
```

Special handling of omitting 1 coeffecients and 0 and 1 exponents left as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [this](https://www.python-course.eu/polynomial_class_in_python.php) which is working well but maybe too complex compared with what you want to achieve (you can compute the derivative, ...).

More particularly, this piece of code can help you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Polynomial:

def __init__(self, *coefficients):
    """ input: coefficients are in the form a_n, ...a_1, a_0 
    """
    # for reasons of efficiency we save the coefficients in reverse order,
    # i.e. a_0, a_1, ... a_n
    self.coefficients = coefficients[::-1] # tuple is also turned into list

def __repr__(self):
    """
    method to return the canonical string representation 
    of a polynomial.

    """
    # The internal representation is in reverse order,
    # so we have to reverse the list
    return "Polynomial" + str(self.coefficients[::-1])

def __call__(self, x):    
    res = 0
    for index, coeff in enumerate(self.coefficients):
        res += coeff * x** index
    return res 

def degree(self):
    return len(self.coefficients)

@staticmethod
def zip_longest(iter1, iter2, fillchar=None):    
    for i in range(max(len(iter1), len(iter2))):
        if i >= len(iter1):
            yield (fillchar, iter2[i])
        elif i >= len(iter2):
            yield (iter1[i], fillchar)
        else:
            yield (iter1[i], iter2[i])
        i += 1   

def __add__(self, other):
    c1 = self.coefficients
    c2 = other.coefficients
    res = [sum(t) for t in Polynomial.zip_longest(c1, c2, 0)]
    return Polynomial(*res[::-1])

def __sub__(self, other):
    c1 = self.coefficients
    c2 = other.coefficients
    res = [t1-t2 for t1, t2 in Polynomial.zip_longest(c1, c2, 0)]
    return Polynomial(*res[::-1])

def derivative(self):
    derived_coeffs = []
    exponent = 1
    for i in range(1, len(self.coefficients)):
        derived_coeffs.append(self.coefficients[i] * exponent)
        exponent += 1
    return Polynomial(*derived_coeffs[::-1])

def __str__(self):
    res = ""
    for i in range(len(self.coefficients)-1, -1, -1):
        res +=  str(self.coefficients[i]) + "x^" + str(i) + " + "
    if res.endswith(" + "):
        res = res[:-3]
    return res
```

Then you can use:

```
 p = Polynomial(-0.8, 2.3, 0.5, 1, 0.2)
```

To get:

[image]

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

`Poly` can instantiate from a list of coefficients. A `defaultdict` can be used to fill in for the missing powers:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int, multiset(f))
>>> Poly.from_list([d[i] for i in range(max(d), -1, -1)], x)
Poly(2*x**6 + 2*x**5 + 3*x**4 + 4*x**3 + x**2 + 3*x, x, domain='ZZ')
>>> _.as_expr()
2*x**6 + 2*x**5 + 3*x**4 + 4*x**3 + x**2 + 3*x
```