# Making a function to return polynomials

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have the list below:

```
p = [['a',[1,2,3,3,3,2]],['b',[3,3,4,14]],['c',[12,12,13,14,15]]]
```

I wish to make a polynomial for 1st element of each sublist, I do as follow, first I define another list:

```
f = [i[1] for i in p]
#[[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2], [3, 2, 4, 14], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

then I define:

```
from sympy import poly, var
from sympy import *
from collections import Counter
x = var("x")
```

and use counter on `f` as:

```
count=[Counter(i) for i in f]
#[Counter({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}),
# Counter({2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 14: 1}),
# Counter({11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1})]
```

Now I want to make a function that return the the polynomials so I do:

```
def pol(m):
    z = []
    for i in m:
         z.append(z.sum(coeff * x ** exp for exp, coeff in count.items()))
    return(z)
```

which does not work, although I know `sum(coeff * x ** exp for exp, coeff in count.items())` is correct way to make the polynomials, for a list of numbers, for example if I do

```
sum(coeff * x ** exp for exp, coeff in count[0].items())
#3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + x
```

I get the right polynomial for the first element.

I wonder what's my mistake when defining the function? Also is there a way to keep the corresponding letters to each polynomial?

Comment: this seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460956/having-a-list-and-trying-to-make-a-polynomial-in-python-symbolic-calculation/57461054#57461054

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes indeed I am trying to build on that.

Comment: missed the append, but also with append doesn't work, am I missing something?

Comment: `z.append(z.sum(coeff * x ** exp for exp, coeff in count[i].items()))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your function `pol(m)` the name `z` is a list and does not have a `.sum` method. you probably want to append to `z`:

```
def pol(m):
    z = []
    for i in m:
        z.append(sum(coeff * x ** exp for exp, coeff in i.items()))
    return z
```

now

```
pol(m=count)
# [3*x**3 + 2*x**2 + x, x**14 + x**4 + 2*x**3, 
#  x**15 + x**14 + x**13 + 2*x**12]
```

will work.